# Create pivot table (bring column to rows) of DataFrame in python

Tags: python

I have my data -

```
data = [['0092', 'ab', '0', '1', '2'], ['887', 'cd', '4', '2', '1'], 
        ['776', 'ef', '2', '1', '3'] ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ('id', 'name', 'W', 'S', 'O'))
df

id   name   W   S   O
0092  ab    0   1   2
887   cd    4   2   1
776   ef    2   1   3
```

I want my output as -

```
id    name  category div
0092    ab  0        W  
0092    ab  1        S
0092    ab  2        O
887     cd  4        W
887     cd  2        S
887     cd  1        O
776     ef  2        W
776     ef  1        S
776     ef  3        O
```

Basically I want to create a pivot table to bring the column to rows and arrange the data according to the change, please help me to get my desired output

Comment: Would you consider handling list before convert it to dataframe?

Comment: yes but just to add on actually i have 3-4 more columns, just to keep it short I posted my qstn with less column

Comment: So `div` and `category` they have the same length, right?

Comment: yes same length

Answer (score 0):

Not the expert on pandas, but you could do it with an easy comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['0092', 'ab', '0', '1', '2'], ['887', 'cd', '4', '2', '1'], 
        ['776', 'ef', '2', '1', '3'] ]
div = ['W','S','O']

res = [{"id":id_, "name": name, "category": category, "div": d} for id_, name, *categories in data for category, d in zip(categories, div)]
print(pd.DataFrame(res))
```

And the result:

```
     id name category div
0  0092   ab        0   W
1  0092   ab        1   S
2  0092   ab        2   O
3   887   cd        4   W
4   887   cd        2   S
5   887   cd        1   O
6   776   ef        2   W
7   776   ef        1   S
8   776   ef        3   O
```